# Hosting non-WCF service on Azure

Tags: wcf, azure

Is it possible to host a non-wcf service on Azure? I'm guessing not. But want to double check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to host non WCF Services via the Windows Azure Service Bus, there was talk at TechEd from Clemens Vasters on a new feature coming soon "IIS Hybrid Cloud Bridge" that should meet this requirement.

More information here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/AZR308

Looks like it will be an open sourced project.

Answer (score 0):

You can host whatever type of service you want. Windows Azure web/worker roles are basically Windows Server 2008 VMs with some scaffolding code. In the `OnStart()` or `Run()`, you can fire up a process that listens on a port (which you also have to create an Input Endpoint for). At that point, you're up and running. This is how you'd run something like MongoDB as well (at least a standalone instance or shard router), where you open up port 27017 and then run mongod.exe with that port number.

Keep in mind: If you have multiple instances of your web or worker role, traffic will be load-balanced across all your instances. Because of that, you need to keep your service stateless, and not assume a visitor will keep arriving at a particular role instance.

**EDIT:** Quick clarification: Your service must be tcp, http, https, or udp-based, as those are the currently-supported port protocols.

Comment: David, thank you for your response. In a hurry, I might have asked the wrong question. My question is really more about Azure AppFabric Service Bus (ASB). I know a client can easily talk to an internal WCF service behind an org's firewall using the ASB. This is accomplished by creating a relay service in the ASB on behalf of the internal service. I'm wondering if this is possible if the internal service is non-WCF.